# Get SIZE of String in iOS 7

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, size, ios7

I use MonoTouch.Dialog (heavily customized) and I used the tableView's StringSize method to get the Size of a string (height and width).  This doesn't work now in iOS 7.  How can I return a Size of a string to get it's height/width so I can perform adjacent control alignments?

Thank you.

Comment: in Obj-C, but same basic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368567/uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-height-in-ios-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var tv = new UITextView() {
    Text = "Some text",
    Font = UIFont.PreferredBody
};
//Pass in a maximum size (in this case, vastly larger than needed)
var neededSize = tv.SizeThatFits(new SizeF(1000, 1000));
Console.WriteLine(neededSize);
```