# UITextView line spacing changed in iOS 7 - how to calculate the old spacing using Core Text

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, core-text, fontmetrics

Looks like the line spacing of `UITextView` changed in iOS 7 (presumably because the underlaying architect of the text view changed to `TextKit`). My iOS project requires that the old pre-iOS 7 line spacing to be maintained.

To adjust the line spacing as needed, I found that the new `NSLayoutManagerDelegate` can be used.

However, I am unable to figure out the logic of evaluating the line spacing to be used (based on font metrics) to mimic the pre-iOS 7 behavior of `UITextView`. The logic needs to be generic as I need it to work for all fonts. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed explanation on line spacing here
[UITableViewCell with UITextView height in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368567/uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-height-in-ios-7)

I use the following function (sizeThatFits) for getting the size of UITextView,

```
    - (CGSize)contentSizeForTextView:(UITextView *)textView
      {
      return [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
      }
```