# UITextView inside UIScrollView doesn`t reach final position

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, parse-platform

I thought that it is going to be an easy thing but I am stuck with scrolling. Height of my `UIScrollView` is equal to the hight sets in my code (700) . I ticked off `Use Autolayout`. And it scrolls but do not show fully text `UITextView` . It is non-editable text, just description of town. It is a large text. I want to make some autofix for `UIScrollView` according to the long  of the `UITextView`. Don`t want free space at the end of UITextView.

Thank you

Right now it looks something like this:
[image]

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <  UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *PopisMesta;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *detailItem;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *deatailedlabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *pocetobyv;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageviewsec;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *viewScroller;

@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize PopisMesta;
@synthesize deatailedlabel;
@synthesize pocetobyv;
@synthesize imageviewsec;
@synthesize viewScroller;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [viewScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [viewScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];

    self.PopisMesta.text = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"PopisMesta"];


    self.deatailedlabel.text = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"MestoName"];


    self.pocetobyv.text = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"PocetObyv"];


    [self.imageviewsec setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];






}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Why have created scroll view your text view can make text scrollable

Comment: Because of I need to display here some Labels, UIImageViews, some Description via UITextView and I want to have it all in one scrollview

Comment: If you want your scroll view scroll so that everything fits and there shouldn't be empty space at the end the you have to calculate the total height which is height of all your components + margin between them. Now how you calculate the variable text view size is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18368567/468724)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am gonna take a look at this.

Comment: Still don`t understand how do you mean it. Because there are just samples for UITableView. Can you give me some examples? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a wrong way! you have to put inside your view in a interface all you need, but you have to use a little trick:

1) open your interface and put your `UIScrollView`

[image]

2) inside a `UIScrollView` put a `UIImageView`

[image]

3) under your image put your text inside a `UILabel` (I know is strange, but is a best and fast way to do wath you want)

[image] [image]

4) follow my screen i made for you ;)

[image]

**To fix Scroll and Text manually follow the screen below**
1) Here is normal view on interface builder

[image: Here is normal view on interface builder]

2) Now set a free form for you ViewController

[image: Now set a free form for you ViewController]

3) Go to size and set what you want long (to see all inside a scroll view)

[image: Go to size and set what you want long (to see all inside a scroll view)]

4) This is a result, set what you want and after remake viewController a 568 Height

[image: This is a result, set what you want and after remake viewController a 568 Height]

Hope this help you!

Comment: First of all thank you for your advice. On the other hand I am still in trouble, because it does not autofix by the long on text, which is in label. Any ideas how to do it? thank you

Comment: With my method you have ti fix manually. add new screen on my answer ;)

Comment: I think you missunderstood what I want. You think that I have some viewcontroller, where I have to display text, which have for example 16lines. But I have Tableview with segue to Detailviewcontroller and theres some data, description of town. And every town, every cell in my table view have different long of text. One has 20lines and other one has 40. I just want to fix the scrollview and don`t want any free spaces under text(I have it under the one with 20lines).

Comment: I tried it by your tutorial and it fixed my problem with scrolling but have the free scape under the text, so it doesn`t cut it according to the long of text.