# Autolayout ScrollView with dynamic content

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder, uitextview, autolayout

im going crazy on autolayout and dynamic scrollview heigth.

I want to make my scrollview content height based on the content in multiple textviews. Also the spacing between the textviews should stay the same.

Therefor i tried to make a small sample app with two textviews and a button which calls `[textview sizeToFit]` for each textview. Another thread suggested to set the bottom verticl spacing of the lowest view to the scrollview (see screen1)

Following problems:

- The vertical spacing between the textviews does not apply correctly (see screenshot3)
- After applying `[textview sizeToFit]` the scrollview isnt scrollable and its size stays the same. Also only textview1 gets scrollable (is set NO in IB)

Im glad for any help or step-by-step tutorials. 
Another thought I had: Would it make sense to put those textviews in a tableview and make cells heigth depending on content, so I dont habe to struggle with scrollview stuff?

More details are on the screenshots:
[image: constraints]
[image: before sizeToFit]
[image: after sizeToFit]

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out, using a UITableView with a custom cell, containing a label on left side and a textview on the right side.

To get the dynamic height in UITableView I used the answer provided in this thread:
[Dynamic Height iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368567/uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-height-in-ios-7).

Further more I added 2 constraints to the UITextView (top and bottom to the cell's content view) to stretch the UITextView to same height as the cell.

Though its not the answer that i wanted (since i tried to use autolayout-only), I hope others can use this approach.