# AutoResizing textView in tableViewCell - iOS 9 (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

I need to expand the height of cell as per text size , How can I calculate the height of the text in textView .

I have used textview in cell to show contents and using constraints to set width which is not static .

Can anyone guide me how can i calculate height of textview ?

Thanks :)

Comment: use self-sizing cell. Don't need to calculate.

Comment: This [link](https://pontifex.azurewebsites.net/self-sizing-uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-in-ios-8/) in Swift, same thing in Objective-C. You can search more.

Comment: i am not using size classes .. Its not performing changes here .

Comment: Use self-sizing cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you some related links about this. You can understand and know how to do it after read that.

[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

[UITableViewCell with UITextView height in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368567/uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-height-in-ios-7)