# How to update UITableViewCell height because of text entered into UITextView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, uitextinput

I have different [**examples**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368567/uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-height-in-ios-7) where we can update the `UITableViewCell` height based on growing `UITextView` which actually is working for me. The issue which I am facing is, I have more subviews below `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. This way, the cell's height updates but the position of the subviews remain fixed which causes overlap of `UITextView` and the subviews. 
Just to mention, I am not using auto layout.
How do I fix this ?
These are the three screenshots which will help in understanding my issue :

**1. Before TextView is shown :**

[image]

**2. After TextView is shown :**

[image]

**3. After text is entered :**

[image]

Comment: In your tableview cell put all your subview(that remain fixed) in one view and when your UITextview height change(increase/decrease) set that view y position below UITextview.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using auto layout for this cell (but we could use a code example or Xcode screenshot to help you more specifically). If you are using auto layout, you'll want to make sure that:

1. You have a constraint between the UITextView and the other UIView subviews below it in the cell
2. The other UIView subviews are eventually constrained to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: I am not using auto layout. And if I change it now, it will be a huge change.

Comment: You need to use auto layouts which will adjust the gap.

Answer (score 3):

Because `UITableViewCell`s are reused, you will find that when adding objects to the `contentView`, those objects will also be reused without being removed, leading to overlapping subviews. The way around this it to start your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the following code:

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    for (UIView * view in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
//        clears the cell before reusing
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using auto layout? I have done this before several times with UITableViewCells though it’s mainly been with UILabel and not UITextView.

Your problem might be resolved with auto layout. You layout all your subviews (inside of UITableViewCell) relative to each other. If one view (i.e. UITextView) changes size the other views will then adjust relative to that view.  Here are a few useful links.

This isn’t specific to UITableViewCell but has a lot of good examples of various scenarios.
Stanford University Developing iOS 7 Apps: Lecture 9 - Animation and Autolayout
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sc7NI6-wo

Comment: I am not using auto layout. And if I change it now, it will be a huge change.

Comment: I understand some view may be too tough to switch over to autolayout. Keep in mind that you can use springs and struts together with autolayout. It doesn't have to stricktly be one or the other. You can also try implementing a custom UIView (.xib) which does autolayout but is a child to a view using springs and struts to isolate how you do the layout.

Comment: I am creating UITableViewCell subviews from code in cellForRowAtIndex and not through xib.

Comment: And I am doing so because cell's UI depends on server data.