# How get UITextView contentView height, if iam using sizeToFit property?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview

How get UITextView contentView height, if Iam using sizeToFit property ?

Comment: If you are using sizeToFit then then don't you use `textView.frame.size.height`

Comment: @NiravD My need is to get no.of lines from UITextView. I got solution as :                  `int numLines = txtview.contentSize.height / txtview.font.lineHeight;`. But I can't get correct textView contentView height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using,

```
 int numLines = txtview.contentSize.height / txtview.font.lineHeight;
```

to get the number of lines in the `textView` then you don't need `sizeToFit` or not required to set `textView`'s frame as per content size.

`txtview.contentSize.height` will give you content view's height and you can get number of lines.

But make sure that you are doing this in `viewDidAppear`(or any where after your view is appeared) not in `viewDidload` because in `viewDidload` your textview is not loaded completely.

Answer (score 1):

UITextView itself has a function called sizeThatFits: which will return the smallest size needed to display all contents of the UITextView inside a bounding box, that you can specify.

The following will work equally for both iOS 7 and older versions and as of right now does not include any methods, that are deprecated.

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText: (NSAttributedString*)text andWidth: (CGFloat)width {
UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[calculationView setAttributedText : text];
CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
return size.height;
}
```

Reference link [UITableViewCell with UITextView height in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368567/uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-height-in-ios-7)